# Browserify and Babel gulp tasks

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I want to use both Browserify and Babel with my JavaScript. For this I created a gulp task

```
gulp.task('babel', function() {
    return gulp.src('_babel/*.js')
        .pipe(browserify({ insertGlobals : true }))
        .pipe(babel({ presets: ['es2015'] }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_dev/js'));
});
```

Unfortunately, when I want to use `import` within my code, I am getting an error:

```
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

My main js file is very simple:

```
import 'directives/toggleClass';
```

I'm guessing that it is because of Babel (and it's `use strict` addition), but what can I do?

Comment: Does changing the order (placing babel before browserify), help at all?

Comment: No, I tried this, and removing `babel` also doesn't help.

Comment: Not an answer, but did you try using https://github.com/babel/babelify instead ?

Comment: you need to make a `.babelrc` file with babel 6

Comment: Browserify works with Common JS modules. You are using ES6 modules. You need to transpile a your ES6 modules to commonJS before using Browserify.

Comment: You should probably elaborate how to do that. Easiest way is using [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify). I tried to comment on your answer Bobby.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Babel maintains an official transform for [Browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) called [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) and it should be used wherever possible if using babel and browserify.

Drop the use of babel directly and place babelify as a transform plugin for browserify. There are many ways to configure browserify but specifying config in your `package.json` would probably be easiest.

```
"browserify": { 
  "transform": [["babelify", { "presets": ["es2015"] }]]
}
```

Your gulp task will then be simplified

```
gulp.task('babel', function() {
    return gulp.src('_babel/*.js')
        .pipe(browserify({ insertGlobals : true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_dev/js'));
});
```

Browserify also exposes methods to do this programmatically so you will be able to configure the bundler from inside your gulp task (dropping the package config, although using the package is perfectly fine for this), check their documentation and experiment, I've done it before but its been a long time since I used gulp (using gulp here is just a complication you dont need, but I expect you are using it elsewhere in your build pipeline where it might be more helpful).